# VB Single line with null values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement, nullable

I have the following code that I don't believe is functioning properly and I cannot figure out why.

```
dim total as decimal? = If(first Is Nothing OrElse second Is Nothing, _
                           Nothing, _
                           Math.Abs(If(first, 0D)) - Math.Abs(If(second, 0D)))
```

If either *first* or *second* are nothing, then nothing needs to be placed in the `total`. However, if they both have values, they both need to be changed to positive values and `first - second` needs to be calculated. First and second are both nullable decimals (decimal?).

Expected results:

```
first = nothing
second = nothing
total = nothing
```

Actual results:

```
first = nothing
second = nothing
total = 0D
```

I cannot understand why the if statement is not jumping to the true segment and putting Nothing into the variable total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reverted to make a compiler extension that allows the absolute value function to be performed on a nullable decimal, returning the value if it is Nothing or non-negative, otherwise multiply by -1 and return. That way if it returns nothing the computation result is as expected.

`dim total as decimal? = first.ToAbsoluteValue() - second.ToAbsoluteValue()`

`<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
 Friend Function ToAbsoluteValue(value As Decimal?) As Decimal?
     If value Is Nothing OrElse value >= 0 Then Return value
     Return Math.Abs(If(value, 0D))
 End Function`

If anyone knows how to add this to the Math.Abs() overloads that would be a much cleaner option.

Answer (score 2):

The `If()` operator is strongly-typed, but the compiler has to infer the type of the result based on the inputs.

In this case, it can't infer the type from the first option (`Nothing`), because Nothing by itself has no type, and unlike C#'s `null`, Nothing can reduce to a value type (this will be important in a moment). Therefore the compiler has to look at the second option: `Math.Abs(If(first, 0D)) - Math.Abs(If(second, 0D))`. The type of this expression evaluates out to a `Decimal`... **not** a `Decimal?`.  Therefore, the resulting type of your entire `If()` expression is a `Decimal`, and not a `Decimal?`. That you assign the result to a `Decimal?` doesn't matter.

> I cannot understand why the if statement is not jumping to the true segment and putting Nothing into the variable total

That is exactly what it's doing. However, as mentioned earlier, `Nothing` in VB.Net can be assigned to value types. Before the assignment can occur, Nothing is converted to a Decimal, because this is the result type of that `If()` expression. In case of a Decimal, assigning the value of Nothing results in the default Decimal value of `0D`... hence your results.

I haven't tested this, but I think you could fix this to get your desired results by explicitly casting the False expression in your `If()` operator as a `Decimal?`/`Nullable(Of Decimal)`. This will tell the compiler to infer `Decimal?` instead of `Decimal` for the type of the `If()` expression, and therefore returning `Nothing` from that expression will have desired output.

Comment: you are not allowed to pass nullable values into Math.Abs()

Comment: Hmm... good to know. Hadn't run into that before. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: therefor the False part will never result in nothing...hence the reason for the precondition checks